# In CrafterCMS, how can I query a model to get an array with all the fields in a repeated group?

Tags: content-management-system, xpathquery

In **CrafterCMS**, I have a component **Team** with a itemSelector field where I'm assigning some instances of another component **TeamMember**.

In the template of **Team** I'm using siteItemService.getSiteItem to get the model information of child components:

```
<#assign memberModel =  siteItemService.getSiteItem(memberItem.storeUrl) />
```

Between the fields of type TeamMember I have:
[Some fields of TeamMember](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11mNJ.png)

I'm able to get the value of skillTitle like this:

```
<#assign skillsTitle = memberModel.queryValue("//skillsTitle")!"" />
```

But I'm not able to get the value of the values in the repeating group.

I tried with:

```
<#assign skills = memberModel.queryValues("//skills")![] />
```

It returns an array of just one element, I think is an empty string

```
<#assign skills = memberModel.queryValues("//skills/item")![] />
```

It returns an array with the right number of elements, but I think all of them are empty strings

If I use:

```
<#assign skills = memberModel.queryValues("//skills/item/skillName")![] />
```

I get a correct array with all the skill names, but I need iterate over both values (skillName and skillLevel)

**How can I query the model in order to get an array which elements have all the values in the repeated group?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you get the SiteItem with

> <#assign memberModel =  siteItemService.getSiteItem(memberItem.storeUrl) />

it works just like any other contentModel variable within a FreeMarker template. So, you can iterate it with

```
<#list memberModel.skills.item as skill>
    ${skill.skillName} = ${skill.skillLevel}
</#list>
```

Comment: This was very helpful!